# Mining in the wallet

Tags: client

Someone said me that I should give him my wallet email and then he will request for the mine from the mining network, after that he asked that you will receive email from that u will get code which u have to send me and then invest your bitcoin wallet with 50$.And after some hours I will get the profit in my wallet. Is this a scam?

Comment: If you did not create the bitcoin address to which the $50 must be sent, then most likely yes.

Comment: This is 100% a scam, mining **does not** work in the way this person has described to you. DO NOT EVER give out your password, private keys, seed phrases, login info, etc, to anybody. There is never any need to, anyone asking for that info is almost certainly trying to rob you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a scam. You do not want to give the private key of your wallet to anyone. Do not deal with this person.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are talking about a private key, but if so NEVER give someone else your private key.
Either way, $50 worth of bitcoin doesn't matter to miners.  They just care about hash power.  Account holdings only matter in PoS.

In the end, yes this sounds like a scam